# NASM Assembly 16bit "invalid combination of opcode and operands"

Tags: assembly, nasm, 16-bit

So I'm trying to write a program that creates a file and  my name in it.
But I get the "invalid combination of opcode and operands" on 
the `mov handle, ax`, and I don't know why. 
I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29569269/writing-a-string-to-a-file-100-times-in-assembly) that you can do it so why can't I.
Thank you in advance for any help.

```
org 100h

mov ah, 3ch     ;create a file
mov dx, name    ;file name
mov cx, 0       
int 21h

mov handle, ax ; save handle

mov ah, 40h     ;write to file
mov bx, handle
mov cx, 1000    
mov dx, text    ; what to write
int 21h

mov ah, 3eh     ;close the file
mov bx, handle
int 21h


mov ax, 4C00h ; end 
int 21h

section .data
name db "name.txt", 0
text db "Michal",0ah,0dh,"$"

section .bss
handle resb 2
```

Comment: what happens if you put the definition of handle at the top like in the example you linked to ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NASM Requires Square Brackets For Memory References](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.08/html/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.2.2). The correct syntax is `mov [handle], ax`. `foo` is using the address and `[foo]` is the content. You might have that mixed up elsewhere too.